# Unable to Initialise WSO2 governance registry?

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

I am trying to customize the index.jsp for wso2 governance registry. I am trying to get the list of all the services that were being added into the registry. And also I want to add functionality like searching for the services in the index.jsp. I am trying to intialize the Registry object ? I am wondering how to get the Registry object. Can any one suggest me how to do that ? so that once I can get the Registry object, I will use Resource object to search in the Registry.

Resource governanceFolder = registry.get("/_system/governance");

But how to get that registry object ?

I tried Registry registry = initialize(); which did not work. Can any one help me ?

Answer (score 0):

What is the GREG version you are using ? In the case if you are using latest GREG (4.5.3) services are also considered as Configurable governance artifacts, Therefor you can follow http://ajithvblogs.blogspot.com/2013/02/how-to-invoke-custom-artifacts-using.html to get list of services.

In case if you are using an old version of GREG you may have to use the corresponding Admin Service to list services.

Answer (score 0):

You can find [[1]](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/4.1.0/products/greg/4.6.0/modules/samples/ws-client/src/org/wso2/carbon/registry/ws/client/sample/SampleWSRegistryClient.java) to initialize the registry object.

```
Registry governanceRegistry = GovernanceUtils.getGovernanceUserRegistry(registry, userName);

ServiceManager serviceManager = new ServiceManager(governanceRegistry);

Service[] services = serviceManager.getAllServices();
```

Find more details on Governance Registry [documentation](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance453/Services+with+Governance+API).